# Only a single click is working in my listview

Tags: listview, xamarin.android

I am developing one Android app in xamarin.android and I implemented the listview and it works fine.but the problem is that I have a button in my custom list and only button click event is execute when I click on the button but the listitemclick event is not executing only button click is working. But I want to implement both click event.

Here is my code

```
internal class MyCustomListAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    private List<AlbumTable> albm;

    public MyCustomListAdapter(List<AlbumTable> albm)
    {
        this.albm = albm;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return albm.Count();
        }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return long.Parse(albm[position].Id);
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var view = convertView;

        if (view == null)
        {
            view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.inflate_album, parent, false);

            var name = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text1);

            view.Tag = new ViewHolder() { Name = name };
        }

        var holder = (ViewHolder)view.Tag;

        holder.Name.Text = albm[position].Id;

        holder.Name.Click += (e, a) =>
            {
                DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper();
                db.DeleteFromTable(albm[position]);
            };
        return view;
    }

}
```

And my listview item click looks like this

```
   myList.ItemClick += (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) =>
        {
            string selectedFromList = e.Position.ToString();
            var activity2 = new Intent(this.Activity, typeof(AlbumViewer));
            activity2.PutExtra("position", e.Position.ToString());

            StartActivity(activity2);
            System.Console.WriteLine(selectedFromList);
        };
```

When I put button only button click work and listview item click doesn't work if I removed a button from design then list item click doesn't work.

How to implement both button and item click?

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with active elements inside a ListView (TextView and ImageView) and I solved transforming the ListView in a LinearLayout... not very orthodox as solution but in my case it worked well also because my lists were very short.
The modification is quite easy and maybe could help you in understanding what's happening.

This is the "list view" inside the layout:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/container_items"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_items"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ScrollView>
```

Here is where I "setup" the list (an Activity in my case):

```
LinearLayout listItems = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.list_items);

// ...

private void RefreshList()
{
    var adapter = new MyAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.item_layout, items);
    Action refreshList = () =>
    {
        listItems.RemoveAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.Count; i++)
        {
            listItems.AddView(adapter.GetView(i, null, listItems));
        }
    };
    adapter.RegisterDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver(refreshList));
    adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And finally this is the GetView of the adapter:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.From(Context);
        v = vi.Inflate(this.layoutId, parent, false);
    }
    MyItem myItem = GetItem(position);

    ImageView btnRemove = v.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.btn_item_remove);

    // ...

    btnRemove.Click += (sender, e) =>
    {
        this.items.Remove(myItem);
        this.Remove(myItem);
        this.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    };

    return v;
}
```